# Is it Possible to copy and Zip a file using 7 zip using cmd prompt?

Tags: command-prompt, 7zip

I need to copy of a FILE and zip the same file.

Comment: Might I suggest that you ask this question at http://superuser.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

This command you can run by keeping the exe in your user directory.

```
    7z e archive.zip
```

e is for extraction
for compression use x